# Use or purpose of a pointer to a pointer (C)

Tags: c, pointers

I understand what a pointer is, but I am struggling to understand what they are used for. I could think of situations where you COULD use a pointer, but these situations I can think of, could also be solved in a different way without much more work. Anyway, what I really do not understand, is the use of pointers to pointers. For example I came across this simple C-code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ...
}
```

From what I understood, this is meant to be a program that can be called by the commandline with infinite parameters and is sort of a convention.
What exactly is the purpose of char** argv? Why use a pointer to a pointer to a char here? I'm sorry if this is a trivial question, but I seem to really struggle to get the big picture here.

Thank you in advance,
Sparkas

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do pointer to pointers work in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/897366/how-do-pointer-to-pointers-work-in-c)

Comment: `argv` is (a pointer to the first element of) an array of `char*`. The array's length is `argc`. Normal array-to-pointer decay applies.

Comment: [Uses of pointers in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337848/could-you-help-me-understand-pointers-please/5341028#5341028)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pointer to a pointer (to a pointer..) is useful in all the situations in which you need more than one level of indirection.

In the specific circumstance of `char** args` you have an array of strings which are the arguments, each string in C is a `char*` so basically you have some thing like

```
char** args
        |
         ->  | char* | char* | char* | char* |
                 |       |
                 v       |
                |f|o|o|  |
                         |
                         v
                        |b|a|r|
```

What's strange about this? Think about that `T*` defines a type which is a pointer to a `T`. Now if `T == char*` then you have that `char**` defines a pointer to a `char*`, which in its turn is a pointer to a `char`.

Remember that in C and C++ a pointer can represent an array.

Comment: I would never have guessed that char **args would point to an array of pointers. I would have just assumed it would point to a single pointer. Although I do not understand how this works, it at least helps me to understand why my given example works the way it does, so thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

There are examples of C where argv is alternately declared as an array of pointers:

```
char *argv[]
```

The pointer to pointer syntax:

```
char **argv
```

declares a pointer to what could be the first pointer in an array of pointers. Another common usage is for passing a pointer to a pointer to a linked list:

```
node *head; /* pointer to linked list */
/* ... */
/* pass a pointer to head */
list_function(&head);
/* ... */
/* use and update head */
list_function(node **head){ ... }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I now know that char **argv points to an array, but I would have intuitively used the char *argv[] way if some had asked me to create an array of pointers. I just don't quite understand how the array is created or declared with **argv. I'd normally assume that it's just a pointer to a single pointer, but maybe that's something I will understand once I learn more about pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Pointers to pointers show up in a number of situations.  Probably the most common is when you need a function to write to a pointer argument.

Consider the following:

```
void foo( T *p ) // for any type T
{
  *p = new_value(); // write to the thing p points to
}

void bar( void )
{
  T var;
  foo( &var ); // foo updates value of var
  ...
}
```

Here the function `foo` is updating the variable `var` defined in `bar` through the pointer `p`.

Now let's replace type `T` with the pointer type `Q *`:

```
void foo( Q **p )
{
  *p = new_pointer_value(); // write to the thing p points to
}

void bar( void )
{
  Q *var;
  foo( &var );  // foo updates the value of var
  ...
}
```

The semantics are exactly the same; we're writing a new value to `var`.  The only difference is that `var` has a pointer type, so we need to use multiple levels of indirection in `foo`.

A second common situation is when you have an array of pointers, and you pass that array to another function.  For example:

```
void foo( char **s )
{
  while ( *s )
    puts( *s++ );
}

void bar( void )
{
  char *strings[] = { "blurga", "bletch", "blah", NULL };
  foo( strings );
}
```

`strings` is an array of pointers to `char`; each element of the array is the address of a string literal (or NULL).  In the call to `foo` the array expression `strings` is converted ("decays") to an expression of type "pointer to pointer to `char`", and the value of the expression is the address of the first element of the `strings` array<sup>1</sup>.  Since the first element of the array is a pointer, then the address of the first element is a pointer to a pointer.

The third case is when you're allocating memory for a 2D array by pieces:

```
T **arr = malloc( sizeof *arr * rows );
if ( arr )
{
  for( size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
  {
    arr[i] = malloc( sizeof *arr[i] * cols );
  }
}
```

---

<sup>1.  Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the examples, I wouldn't have thought of that and it helps in understanding the use of pointers